# Getting error when using plot.gbm to produce marginal plots

Tags: r, gbm

Total novice to R - 
I am trying to make some marginal plots from a BRT I completed with the gbm package and keep getting the same error.
Below is my code; boosted.tree_LRFF is the output I got from completing a  gbm.fit

```
> plot.gbm(boosted.tree_LRFF, 
+          i.var= 5,
+          n.trees = train.model$finalModel$tuneValue$n.trees,
+          continuous.resolution = 100,
+          return.grid = FALSE,
+          type = "link")
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: Please, review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

In this first section I just re-create the dataset used to fit a gbm from the "gbm.pdf" for the package:

```
library(gbm)
N <- 1000
X1 <- runif(N)
X2 <- 2 * runif(N)
X3 <- ordered(sample(letters[1:4], N, replace = TRUE), levels = letters[4:1])
X4 <- factor(sample(letters[1:6], N, replace = TRUE))
X5 <- factor(sample(letters[1:3], N, replace = TRUE))
X6 <- 3 * runif(N)
mu <- c(-1, 0, 1, 2)[as.numeric(X3)]
SNR <- 10 # signal-to-noise ratio
Y <- X1 ** 1.5 + 2 * (X2 ** .5) + mu
sigma <- sqrt(var(Y) / SNR)
Y <- Y + rnorm(N, 0, sigma)
# introduce some missing values
X1[sample(1:N, size = 500)] <- NA
X4[sample(1:N, size = 300)] <- NA
data <- data.frame(Y = Y, X1 = X1, X2 = X2, X3 = X3, X4 = X4, X5 = X5, X6 = X6)

boosted.tree_LRFF <-
gbm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6,
data = data,
var.monotone = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
distribution = "gaussian",
n.trees = 1000,
shrinkage = 0.05,
interaction.depth = 3,
bag.fraction = 0.5,
train.fraction = 0.5,
n.minobsinnode = 10,
cv.folds = 3,
keep.data = TRUE,
verbose = FALSE,
n.cores = 1)
```

Now I plot the tree function values for variable x5, similar to your plot:

```
plot(boosted.tree_LRFF,
i.var = 5,
n.trees = boosted.tree_LRFF$n.trees,
continuous.resolution = 100,
return.grid = FALSE,
type = "link")
```

I think your error is due to the n.trees argument.  You can either enter it as a constant or it can be from a GBM fitted object.  In my example I used it from "boosted.tree_LRFF" that appears to be the name of the original fitted object in your example (although of course my data was different).